# VBA Exporting Chart Arrays on Button Click

Tags: vba

```
 Sub onButtonClick()

Dim source As Worksheet, target As Worksheet
Set source = Workbooks("End Market Monitor.xlsm").Worksheets("Aero Graphs")
Set target = Sheet1

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim title_name As String, search As String



search = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value
ReDim chartArray(1 To source.ChartObjects.Count) As Chart
For i = 1 To source.ChartObjects.Count
    title_name = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart.ChartTitle.Text
    counter = 1
    If InStr(title_name, search) > 0 Then
        Set chartArray(counter) = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart
        counter = counter + 1
    End If

Next
Set wsTemp = Sheets.Add

    tp = 10

    With wsTemp
        For n = 1 To UBound(chartArray)
            chartArray(n).CopyPicture
            wsTemp.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
            Selection.Top = tp
            Selection.Left = 5
            tp = tp + Selection.Height + 50
        Next
    End With

    wsTemp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NewFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
           IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

I'm having trouble with the search variable. I keep getting object defined error and I have no idea why... Should I be using Cells.Offset?

Also, when I loop through the array of charts, I am unable to use the for each loop so I had to loop through from 1 to the upper bound of the array. Is this viable?

Comment: On what line are you getting the "Object Defined" error?

Comment: On the search = Activecell.offset(0,-5). At the same time, I get the copypicture method failed for chartArray.

Answer (score 0):

The Object-Defined error is popping up because `ActiveCell.Offset(0,-5)` is trying to pick a cell that doesn't exist. If the ActiveCell is in column A,B,C,D or E it will show this error because there is no column before A. Perhaps be more specific then "ActiveCell".

As for looping through charts, the following should work:

```
Dim ChartObj as Chartobject
For each ChartObj in Source.ChartObjects
    ....
Next ChartObj
```